# Web storage options

Tags: cookies, web, storage

I need to have some script on my webpage which enables viewers to identify what internal links they opened on previous visits. I have looked at cookies and web storage. First prize would be a box in which their previous link views were listed.
Complete scripts tags and where they go to solve this will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you're going to be given a complete solution here, but here are some general thoughts:

- Use a cookie and/or local storage to identify a user. If there's a login system even better, you can uniquely identify any logged in user.
- Create a database table for storing visited pages. The format depends upon what other information you want to stored, e.g. how many times they visited, when they visited, etc. But the basic info would be User ID and Relative Page URL.
- Every time a page is hit, insert/update the visit table appropriately.
- For the box of links simply get the distinct URLs visited by that user and format appropriately (perhaps you need a lookup to get the friendly page name).